# invalid use of 'this' outside of a non-static member function error?

Tags: c++, ios, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I am using CCTouchTargetedDelegate with a Class subclassed by CCSprite.
when defining delegate methods i am not being able to use "this" inside the functions.

as answered on previously asked questions
I couldn't used name of class with the function using scope resolution , because it then gave me error of 
"Out-of-line definition of 'ccTouchBegan' does not match any declaration in 'mygames::DragSprite'"

I also tried to declare the function in .h file but nothing seems to work.

My code is as below :-

**.h File**

```
#pragma once
#include "cocos2d.h"




namespace mygames
{

    class DragSprite: public cocos2d::CCSprite, public cocos2d::CCTargetedTouchDelegate
    {
        public:
            DragSprite* createWithFile(const char *pszFileName);
            bool isTouchingOnSprite(cocos2d::CCPoint  touch);
            virtual bool init();
        bool ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent);
        static inline cocos2d::CCPoint ccpSub(const cocos2d::CCPoint v1, const cocos2d::CCPoint v2);
        private:
            bool isDrag;
            cocos2d::CCPoint whereTouch;
    };
}
```

**.cpp File**

```
#include "DragSprite.h"


using namespace mygames;


bool DragSprite::init()
{
    if (!CCSprite::init()) {
        return false;
    }

    whereTouch = cocos2d::CCPointZero;
    isDrag = false;

    return true;
}
DragSprite* DragSprite::createWithFile(const char *pszFileName)
{
    DragSprite *pSprite = new DragSprite();
    if (pSprite&&pSprite->initWithFile(pszFileName))
    {
        cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getTouchDispatcher()->addTargetedDelegate(pSprite, 0, true);
        pSprite->autorelease();
        return pSprite;
    }
    CC_SAFE_DELETE(pSprite);
    return NULL;
}

bool DragSprite::isTouchingOnSprite(cocos2d::CCPoint  touch)
{

    if (this->boundingBox().containsPoint(touch)) {
        return true;
    }else
    {
        return false;
    }    

}
static inline cocos2d::CCPoint ccpSub(const cocos2d::CCPoint v1, const cocos2d::CCPoint v2)
{
    return ccp(v1.x-v2.x, v1.y-v2.y);

}
//CCTargetedTouchDelegate
bool ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
{

    cocos2d::CCPoint touchPoint = pTouch->getLocation();

    if (this->isTouchingOnSprite(touchPoint)) {
        this->whereTouch = ccpSub(this->position, touchPoint);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The Error Screen Shot :-

[image]

What am i missing here ?

**JUST OUT OF CURIOSITY**

AS suggested in the answers, If i use

```
bool DragSprite::ccTouchBegan
```

So, Would it still call the delegete function ? or just the function from my DragSprite class. I mean, would the function be still overridden ?
well...
its the method declared in CCTargetedTouchDelegete. and i guess its an abstract function.

Comment: isn't the error message clear enough? you need `DragSprite::`

Comment: You are missing the class scope in the `bool ccTouchBegan` definition.

Comment: @BryanChen : ok i get it, but how should i use the class pointer. actually i am porting code from Objective-C. and there has been use of "self" ?

Comment: @DemonSOCKET There are a few places that an explicit `this` is required in C++, in most other places (including here) it is considered bad style.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

```
bool ccTouchBegan(
```

needs to be

```
bool DragSprite::ccTouchBegan(
```

You shouldnt need `this` in the first place.

Comment: its the method declared in CCTargetedTouchDelegete. and i guess its an abstract function. So, if i do as you suggested? Would it still call the delegete function ? or just the function from my DragSprite class. I  mean, would the function be still overridden ?

Comment: @DemonSOCKET hmm good question, I think your porting is missing one more element. In C++ virtual functions are opt-in, unlike obj-c. You want to use `virtual` to make this method a "virtual" function, then it will work as in obj-c. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_function for more info. Just add `virtual` before the function definition

Comment: OK.. Well, since it is already declared in CCTargetedTouchDelegate class from which i am inheriting, as of like the following  virtual bool ccTouchBegan(CCTouch *pTouch, CCEvent *pEvent)
     {
         CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pTouch);
         CC_UNUSED_PARAM(pEvent);
         return false;
     };         Do i still need to declare this in .h file ? if yes then with or without virtual keyword ?

Comment: @DemonSOCKET the `virtual` needs to be in the class definition, in the `.h` file

Answer (score 0):

Why not define your function as

```
bool DragSprite::ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
```

which is how you have it defined in the DragSprite class in your .h file.

Comment: its the method declared in CCTargetedTouchDelegete. and i guess its an abstract function. So, if i do as you suggested? Would it still call the delegete function ? or just the function from my DragSprite class. I mean, would the function be still overridden ?

Comment: I'd answer this question, but since you've also specifically asked the other two people who answered your question also I'll give them a shot first. :-)

Comment: well... i am not getting any satisfactory answer with those comments. so would you please help me out here ?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
bool ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
```

defines a stand alone function. this can only be used within a class member function. To make it a class member as you have defined it, you need to qualify the name:

```
bool DragSprite::ccTouchBegan(cocos2d::CCTouch *pTouch, cocos2d::CCEvent *pEvent)
```

-=-=-=-=

I see everyone jumped in at once. The syntax of objective C is different. It uses

```
@implementation DragSprite
 . . . . 

@end
```

to specify the class and requires a - to indicate a non static member function.

Another difference is that Objective C requires self referencing to call a member function

```
[self DragSprite] ;
```

C++ does not

```
DragSprite () ;
```

Comment: its the method declared in CCTargetedTouchDelegete. and i guess its an abstract function. So, if i do as you suggested? Would it still call the delegete function ? or just the function from my DragSprite class. I mean, would the function be still overridden ?

Comment: The next question is what are  you porting? Is the code calling the delegate going to be in C++ too? If it's objective C, that's going to be a problem.

Comment: well.. no its not in the objective-C. by porting i mean i am just using the logic here. because cocos2d-x and cocos2d-iPhone are mostly same. Apologies, if i caused you any confusions.

Comment: also .. i am very much new to cocos2dx and c++. so just for a hint, is it a must to declare any virtual function(not pure) of base class in .h file too ?

Comment: Yes. This is another difference between objective C and C++. It's larger. All member functions must be declared in the header. Objective C allows members to be defined in the body without a declaration.